# How to apply class method scope without a data table column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

**Disclaimer: first question, rails newbie, please be detailed in responses.**

I’m trying to create a filter with a class method that is based off a simple equation performed on two columns in my data table. I can’t figure out how to get the query/filter going such that it filters results based on the results of my equation. Here is an abbreviated set up of my table:

```
t.integer   “horizontal_length” 
t.integer   “thirty_day_flow_rate”
```

I want a filter based off this equation: ( thirty_day_flow_rate / horizontal_length ), so users could say, "show me all the wells with a 30 day flow rate greater than 'x' barrels per foot of length"

I have created a method in my model to hold the equation and it works fine when I call it on a Well object:

```
class Well < ActiveRecord::Base

def flow_rate_per_foot
  thirty_day_flow_rate / horizontal_length
end
```

However, when I want to create a filter based on the results of the equation, I am not sure how to proceed.  I tried something like this, with the mimimum_flow_rate param passed in from the controller:

```
class Well < ActiveRecord::Base

def self.flow_rate_filter(minimum_flow_rate)
  if mimimum_flow_rate.present?
    where(‘flow_rate_per_foot >= ?', minimum_flow_rate)
  else
    Well.all
  end
end
```

Obviously that does not work, because flow_rate_per_foot is not a column in my data table to be called.  How can i work around this? Is there another way to solve this problem?  I want to do this type of filtering for a number of different equations and columns, so any solution needs to be flexible. Thanks!

For reference, my controller is shown below and other filters I have set up that run directly from my data table work properly:

```
def index
   @wells = Well.flow_rate_filter(params[:mimimum_flow_rate])
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you could try using scopes or just query it manually like

@wells = Well.where("(30_day_flow_rate / horizontal_length) >= ?", params[:mimimum_flow_rate])

Comment: The database is going to complain about that `30_day_flow_rate` identifier. The OP is already using a scope (remember that ["Using a class method is the preferred way to accept arguments for scopes"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments)).

Comment: ah yes. just like the answer above, it should be changed to "thirty_day_flow_rate"

Answer (score 0):

What I wanted to do initially does not seem possible.

I solved the problem by creating a new field in my table to hold the "flow_rate_per_foot" calculation that I had originally placed in the flow_rate_per_foot method.

Once the result of the calculation had its own field, I could then filter, search and sort based on the results, which was my overall goal.

Answer (score -1):

Add this line in your model

```
class Well < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessor :minimum_flow_rate
...
```